# Changing Admin Password on TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

When I setup my TeamCity instance, I created the admin user as "buildServerAdmin".  I also create some individual user accounts with admin rights.  I was then not involved with the build server for several months.

Now I can no longer log in using the user name and password I set up originally.  I can log in as myself (I have admin rights), but I don't see that user at all.

I have also logged in as a super user using instructions found [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Super+User).  I don't see buildServerAdmin user when logged in this way either.

My questions:

1. Is there anything special about the original admin user, vs. super user or user configured as Admin?
2. Would I be able to see this user on the Admin => User pages if it existed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phil,
there is nothing special about original admin user, except that this user has broad permissions. If it existed, you would be able to see it on the users page in administration section.

I would advise to check Audit section (Administration -> Audit). There you can select 'UserActions :: Create/Delete' to see whether the original user was deleted